# pagejs and Polymer data-route in child components

Tags: polymer

To seperate master-detail views from my index page I created an parent view (ie user-view.html) where user-list and user-detail are encapsulated.
From within user-view I can control events from list and detail.

I want this master-detail work with url. So with pagejs I configured my routes. Switching between both (in neon-animated-pages) is working very fine, when list and detail are both directly in my neon-animated-pages tag.

But when I add them to user-view (and put user-view in the neon-animated-pages tag) the data-route attribute on list or detail is not triggered.

How can I make data-route attribute work when encapsulated in another 'parent' component?
index.html:

```
    <neon-animated-pages class="flex" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
            <home-view data-route="home"></home-view>
            <user-view  ></user-view>
          </neon-animated-pages>
```

user-view.html:

```
<template>
        <user-list data-route="users" type="{{type}}" on-user-tap="onUserTap"></user-list>
        <user-detail data-route="user-info" user="{{selectedUser}}" type="{{type}}"></user-detail>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the local DOM of your `user-view.html` into an `iron-pages` or `neon-animated-pages` and you need two routes (one for the parent `neon-animated-pages` and one for the child one inside of `user-view`)

Something along these lines should work:

```
<neon-animated-pages class="flex" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
        <home-view data-route="home"></home-view>
        <user-view data-route="users" route="[[subroute]]" ></user-view>
      </neon-animated-pages>

<template>
    <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[subroute]]">
      <user-list data-route="users" type="{{type}}" on-user-tap="onUserTap"></user-list>
      <user-detail data-route="user-info" user="{{selectedUser}}" type="{{type}}"></user-detail>
    </iron-pages>
</template>
```

In your pagejs handler you need to set the `subroute` for the corresponding routes (user detail/list)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've already tried it before, and now I copied your snippet (to avoid typos). But it leaves a blank when go to users of user-info route.

Comment: do you have the `route` in your `properties` definition of your `user-view` ?

Comment: ah yeah actually you need two routes instead of just one. I updated the answer